# How do I check which VHDL2008 features are supported?

Tags: vhdl

VHDL2008 can be enabled for synthesis tools. This doesn't mean all features of the standard are supported. For example:

> ERROR: Line 45 : The "Vhdl 2008 Package Instantiation Declaration" is
>   not supported yet for simulation.

The features supported are usually mentioned in the documentation, so constraints can be set manually based on this.

Can we constrain the VHDL project not to use certain features of the language?

Comment: Manually you can write any code as you want, so can use project coding guidelines asking to stay in -93, for example. So I guess you're asking about automatically generated code? From what tools???

Comment: Vendor tools from Xilinx, Altera, Lattice only support a subset of -08. VHDL2008 is partially required, at least. Usually I do not compile my code with all tools simultaneously and problems arise when I port the project. I am aware of the limitations for every tool through documentation, but how can I make sure a project meet the coding guidelines?

Comment: - Should be doable with personalized lint(er) rules. - If you don't allow any 2008 construct, compiling with the correct argument will fail all their calls, like with modelsim "The vcom command compiles using -2002 rules by default; use the -87, -93, or -2008 arguments to vcom to compile units written with version 1987, 1993, or 2008 respectively."

Comment: If you have specific new keywords to exclude, you can always use grep too!

Comment: The particular feature requires lexical and syntactical analysis **package** *identifier* **is new** *uninstantiated_package_name* where **is new** only occurs in package and subprogram instantiation after comments are disregarded in IEEE Std 1076-2008 conforming design specifications. Some features require semantic analysis (e.g. implicitly applied condition operators), out of reach of Lint type tools. The answer to your yes/no question is *maybe*, depending on the effort you're willing to apply developing tools and methodology. Testing vendor synthesis eligibility would be even harder.

Comment: Using -87, -93 arguments etc doesn't work for a **subset** of a standard. I would think that semantic analysis is overkill for me but I wasn't aware that this could be a requirement for the problem to solve. To my understanding, testing eligibility is not necessary (I was thinking of defining rules for unsupported features based on documentation).

Comment: Isnt another problem that the VHDL 2008 features supported vary between tools? so you cant really have a common lexer. And then you have the even bigger problem of xilinx saying they support a feature when its actually broken.

Comment: @Tricky I once had a project with a BSoD (system crash) when building. Turns out it was a '08 feature that caused a memory leak in doxygen... so that IS a problem, yes. My intent is to find a compromise between not using '08 at all and an expensive 3rd party synthesizer. The lexer should detect all features that are causing problems with any tool I am currently using. Am I climbing the wrong ladder?

Comment: Assuming you're part of an engineering team there's opportunity for organizational guidelines and design reviews. For a small organization there's direct personal experience. For those in the mid-range there's opportunity to author 'lessons-learned'. It's likely you can't produce something useful without both lexical and syntactical analysis. There are cases of that you can't deal with without semantic analysis (here meaning declarations and examining expresssions). I don't personally believe the effort is worth while. It'd also be hitting a moving target as feature adoption marches forward.

Comment: @jack.sparrow Personally, I think the easiest solution, if you have a problem, is to just stick to vhdl 93. There isn't really much 2008 brings to synthesisable vhdl you can't work around in '93. That was the solution at previous employment when we had to use altera and xilinx. Now I only use xilinx, so it's easy to stick with supported code.